# Bind data to controller after bootstrapping an AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, bootstrapping

Is there any way to bind anything you could have written on a form before bootstrapping an AngularJS application?

For example, in this form (also executable in https://jsbin.com/womuyi). How could bind to the controller the data I've written on the `input` before clicking the bootstrap `button`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Angular Bootstrap Call Example">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  Please type something before bootstrapping AngularJS
  
  <form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.sth"><br/>
    You wrote {{ vm.sth }}
  </form>
  
  <button onclick="doBootstrap()">Bootsrap AngularJS</button>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular
      .module('main', [])
      .controller('MainCtrl', function(){
        var vm = this;
        // How to bind what I wrote on the input after bootstrap??
      });
    
    function doBootstrap() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['main']);
      document.querySelector('button').disabled = 'disabled'
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite ugly, but you can use document to store the values (or any other object that you want) to wait until your app is bootstrapped.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Angular Bootstrap Call Example">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  Please type something before bootstrapping AngularJS

  <form>
    <input id="sthInput" type="text" ng-model="vm.sth"><br/>
    You wrote {{ vm.sth }}
  </form>

  <button onclick="doBootstrap()">Bootsrap AngularJS</button>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular
      .module('main', [])
      .controller('MainCtrl', function(){
        var vm = this;
        vm.sth = document.myBootstrap.sth;
      });

    function doBootstrap() {
      var sthValue = document.querySelector("#sthInput");

      document.myBootstrap = {
        sth: sthValue.value
      };


      angular.bootstrap(document, ['main']);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @iLoveJS probably he needs a variable before ng-app has been executed, so using ng-app would not work. For example, he haves different servers routed to the same domain and he wants to know in which server he is to provide a different behaviour if he's in US or China.

Comment: Thank you @elecash. Despite I have some problems because there's a lot of async controller loading *after* my app's bootstrap, this seems to be the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-app directive before controller as below:

```
<body ng-app="main" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
```

This will automatically do the bootstrapping for you.
The official documentation for the same can be found at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp.

Comment: As @elecash said, I need to do some work before bootstrapping my application, so using ngApp is not an option

Answer (score 0):

you just save value of text box before bootstrap Angular App:-

```
   `beforeData = (document.querySelectorAll(".beforeBootstrap")[0]).value;
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    $event.target.disabled = 'disabled';`
```

[see this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/426SP7AT6RwhZxPfdqPu?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by doing something along the lines of processing input data before Bootstrap like @elecash suggested, but I would add it to a constant.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.doBootstrap = function() {
      window.values = {};
      var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input'),
          input;

      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
        input = inputs[i];
        window.values[input.getAttribute('ng-model')] = input.value;
      }

      angular.bootstrap(document, ['main']);
    }
}());
```

Then in your Angular code:

```
angular
    .module('main', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['preBootstrap', function(preBootstrap){
        var vm = this;
        angular.forEach(preBootstrap, function(value, key) {
          var modifiedKey = key.replace('vm.', '');
          this[modifiedKey] = value;
        }, vm);
    }])
    .constant('preBootstrap', window.values);
```

Comment: That was my solution, after @elecash's proposal, thanks!